# How to hide stereotype display for elements in a diagram

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

When I create an element and add that to a diagram from a C# add-in, the element does show its stereotype. Is there a way to hide the sterotype label for the element in the diagram?

Comment: What do you mean? The stereotype is part of the element. Either you control a shape script to modify the shape or you show it.

Comment: Yes But I dont want it to appear with lable in the diagram

Comment: So when we create elements in the C# addin is there any api to disable the sterotype as lable for element in diagarm

Comment: When we click on the diagram properties we have one option "show Element Stereotypes" So using EA Api can we uncheck this option from C# Addin

Comment: So you're after this 'show element stereotypes' in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `Diagram.ExtendedStyle`. Look for a part string `HideEStereo=0;` and replace it with `HideEStereo=1;` or append this string.